# How to embed glyphicon in the grid generated by tableau

Tags: tableau-api

Currently one of our application is planned for rewrite and most of the html is to be replaced by tableau, though the POC is shaping up as expected we are struck with the part where one of the columns in the tableau  grid should be prepended with an glyphicon and respective click even should be handled, can someone explain me how to achieve this?

Comment: need more specific information... Are you customizing tableau server UI? Where do you want to put glyphicon?

Comment: Exactly, let's say tableau server UI paints 3 columns A,B,C as a table, now my requirement is to add an glyphicon before the value in column B.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to do it is to add the glyphicons that you want to use as custom shapes. They need to be individual png files so your glyphicons would need to be converted. There is a really great tutorial in the Tableau KB about adding these based on what you are trying to show. Rather than copy paste other's work, there are 2 tutorials I believe will address what you are trying to do.

[Adding images inline tutorial](http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/kpis)

There is also this awesome tutorial on adding custom shapes. You should be able to combine the shapes with whatever value you are trying to show.

[How to use custom shapes in Tableau](http://www.tableau.com/about/blog/2016/2/how-use-custom-shapes-filters-your-dashboard-50200)

I can't speak to how you want the click handled because you didn't specify the action that you want to follow the click. If it is supposed to link to another page or trigger a filter, you can add an action via Worksheet > Actions... or Dashboard > Actions... menus

I understand that this no specifically what you were looking for, but glyphicons are technically a custom font and Tableau does not handle custom fonts well. See this post about that in more detail.

[Custom Fonts on Tableau Server](https://community.tableau.com/thread/144077)